# Laravel model join four tables with condition and group by date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I have four tables `technologies(id, name), tasks(id, name), requests(id, status_id, comment, task_id, created_at), technology_task(id, task_id, technology_id)`

I want to get the `requests` whose `status_id` is `2` and join the `tasks` table which has specific `technologies` inserted in the `technology_task` pivot table. I want to group the result based on the date column `created_at`. Is this possible through Lravel model eloquent? I have tried the below method.

```
$this->model
        ->with('task', 'task.technologies')
        ->where('status_id', 2)->get()
        ->groupBy(function ($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')
```

This is the `Request` model and this will return all the requests whose `status_id` is `2` along with the related `task` and `technologies`. But I only want the `requests` whose `task` have specific `technologies`, and I want to check that using something like `->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get()`
How to achieve this using model? or do I need to use a custom query

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$this->model` is your `Request` model, and all your relationships are set correclty, you can use `whereHas`:

```
$technologyIds = [1, 2, 3];

$collection = $this->model
    ->with(['task', 'task.technologies'])
    ->whereHas('task.technologies', function($query) use ($technologyIds)
    {
        // here you can check using whereIn
        $query->whereIn('technologies.id', $technologyIds);
    })
    ->where('requests.status_id', 2)
    ->get();
```

If you want to use the `groupBy` inside the MySQL query, you will need to define what data should MySQL select when grouping. You can achieve that using [aggregation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html). You weren't clear about the data you want to select, the code bellow should return:

- the greatest id of the grouped rows,
- unique comments concatenated with space
- created_at

```
$technologyIds = [1, 2, 3];

$collection = $this->model
    ->with('task', 'task.technologies')
    ->whereHas('task.technologies', function($query) use ($technologyIds)
    {
        $query->whereIn('technologies.id', $technologyIds);
    })
    ->where('requests.status_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('requests.created_at')
    ->selectRaw('
        MAX(requests.id) AS id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT requests.comment
                     ORDER BY requests.comment ASC SEPARATOR ' ') AS comments,
        requests.created_at
    ')
    ->get();
```

Check out the docs to see how each [aggregation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) works.

Comment: Thank you! For grouping, I used the grouping method I used in my question.